# Program "arm-none-eabi-g++" not found in PATH, Program "arm-none-eabi-gcc" not found in PATH

Tags: c, eclipse, gdb, g++, mingw-w64

I am excited to write my first program in C language with Eclipse.

I have done steps 1 to 4 under *Prerequisites* given on  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw.

However,

1. The following commands to check MinGW installation are not recognized in command prompt.

   `g++ --version`

   `gdb --version`
2. The folder `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` is empty.
3. Eclipse is throwing the following two errors:

   `Program "arm-none-eabi-g++" not found in PATH`

   `Program "arm-none-eabi-gcc" not found in PATH`

Can someone please help me with solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the linked documentation suggests, did you check your `PATH` environment variable? This problem has nothing to do with Eclipse, it is just showing you the same diagnosis as the command prompt. -- Probably you need to add the path to the compilers, and please remember to restart the command prompt and Eclipse. Running processes don't receive environment changes.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I have changed the `PATH` and restarted my computer altogether. But am still getting the same errors...

Comment: Well, you need to resolve the issue in the command prompt first. Until you can call GCC in the shell, it makes no sense to try in any IDE. -- You might like to show us where "g++.exe" (or "arm-none-eabi-g++.exe") is on your harddisk, and what contents your `PATH` has. -- A computer restart is not necessary after changing `PATH`, only a newly started "cmd" (or any other application that needs it).

Comment: Hi, I followed the instructions given on [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) and set `PATH` to `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`. This folder is empty by the way, and I don't know if that's how it should be. Also, I looked in all folders under `C:\msys64` but did not find "g++.exe" (or "arm-none-eabi-g++.exe")... I don't know what's wrong :(

Comment: I found `gcc` and `g++` under `C:\msys64\usr\share\bash-completion\completions`. However, these are not .exe files (files without an extension) and I can see their content with Notepad++.

Comment: OK, the findings in "completions" might be just helpers of your bash. It seems as if your MinGW installation is defect. Did you follow the instruction on [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), as the page you linked says?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I was facing errors when downloading the MinGW installation file from MSYS2 page. So, the IT guy from my company downloaded it from somewhere and gave it to me. Probably that .exe file itself had some detect. It occurred to me now when you mentioned it...

Comment: Well, then get this installation fixed. ;-) There are alternatives. For example, some people use [TDM-GCC](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/).